# Div Transparency Doesn't Work in IE8

Tags: css, cross-browser, styles, sass

I have an overlay div that is a child of the body tag The div's background should be transparent white and I would prefer to not fake it with a png. I have the following sass:

```
.my-overlay
    @include opacity(0.6)
    background: #fff
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
```

This compiles to:

```
.my-overlay
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
```

I also have the following

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Transparency works in Chrome, Safari and FF but not IE8. In IE8, the div's background is rendered opaque white (I'm testing in XP/IE8/VMWare on OS X). It doesn't work in compatibility mode either.

I also tried manually changing filter to -ms-filter, which had no effect.

The IE8 developer toolbar shows the filter property has been applied to the div with the correct value, and hasLayout is -1. What could I be overlooking that's preventing transparency in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) works for me, even in IE7/IE8:

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: FYI, this will make everything inside its container transparent too, which will not give some people the desired effect.